# IOS (simulator) --> Local Vapor POST Image/png: Abort.413: Payload Too Large

Tags: swift, vapor, xcode15

**Environment:** 
 Vapor (v4.77+) 
 MacOS v13.4.1

**Scenario:** Attempting to POST image/png (466 kb) to Server. 
The server is local to my Mac: http://localhost:8080/upload  
This is running concurrently with my **Xcode iOS Simulator.**

**Xcode's info.plist:** 
[image]

**Result:**

> Initial Payload:  PayloadModel(filename: "ToiletOnTheSea", contentType: "image/png", data: 466220 bytes)
> Status Code: 413

Here's the Data model:

```
 struct PayloadModel: Codable {
    let filename: String
    let contentType: String
    let data: Data

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case filename
        case contentType
        case data
    }
 }
```

Here's the iOS client:

```
func uploadImageToServer() async {
        let sampleImage = "ToiletOnTheSea"

        guard let image = UIImage(named: sampleImage), let imageData = image.pngData() else {
            showAlert("No Image", "I couldn't access \(sampleImage)")
            print("Error converting image to data")
            return
        }

        let payload = PayloadModel(filename: sampleImage, contentType: "image/png", data: imageData)

        var request = URLRequest(url: serverURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        print("Initial Payload: ", payload)

        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(payload)
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

                if let serverData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse.self, from: data) {
                    let contentType = serverData.payload.contentType
                    let message = serverData.message
                    let filename = payload.filename
                    let count = payload.data.count

                    print("contentType: ", contentType)
                    print("filename: ", filename)
                    print("data count: ", count)

                    showAlert("Server Data", message)

                } else {
                    showAlert("Server-Response Error", "Unable to decode server response")
                }

                // Process data if needed
            } else {
                print("Error: Unexpected response")
            }
        } catch {
            showAlert("Error", "\(error)")
        }
    }
```

Here's the Vapor v4 corresponding server (in Route file):

```
struct ServerResponse: Content {
    let message: String
    let payload: PayloadModel?

    // Provide an initializer that takes the required parameters
    init(message: String, payload: PayloadModel? = nil) {
        self.message = message
        self.payload = payload
    }

    // Implement the required initializer for the Decodable protocol
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        payload = try container.decodeIfPresent(PayloadModel.self, forKey: .payload)
    }

    // Define coding keys to match the properties
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message
        case payload
    }
}



func storeImage(req: Request) async throws -> ServerResponse {
//    let payload = try req.content.decode(PayloadModel.self)
    let response = ServerResponse(message: "Holy Shit, Batman! I'm from storeImage!!", payload: nil)
    return response
}
```

I reduce the codes to a minimum to find the reason for the size rejection. 
I had sent (Posted) a string that succeeded without size error.

2. I had thought there was a Vapor size constraint, so I had set it to a higher size than the image size, which didn't change the outcome. Hence I commented:

[image]

**Question:** Why the size problem, what's causing it and what remedy:

> [ WARNING ] Abort.413: Payload Too Large [request-id:
> 3224652A-0F82-43E9-AA7A-92496FB7781D]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Vapor collects the body from the stream into memory before hitting your route handler. To stop it so that your app isn't vulnerable to a DDOS Vapor specifies a default limit.

You can either increase the limit globally or set it just for that one route. It's in the docs here

https://docs.vapor.codes/basics/routing/#body-streaming